# Touchpad issues with 13.10 macpro retina

Tags: touchpad, mac, macbook, multi-touch

I've had ubuntu on my mac retina for a while now. Initially I installed it back in a 12.x release which came with quite sophisticated touch support. It had 2 and 3 button gestures, however these were unintuative for me and I followed this guide:

http://task3.cc/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/#comment-27468

This enabled me to come up with some kind of hybrid between a mac and ubuntu which I was happy with. FYI - I've been using linux for far longer than a mac, but I find mac's touch support to be excellent and wanted something more similar.

At some point my mac had dead pixels and I exchanged for a new one. For time reasons I didn't repeat the above step....

Additionally I was locked out of ubuntu for a while after a somewhat annoying Mavericks update... I've just come back updated to 13.10 and the touchpad experience is terrible and I'm not able to fix:

- I can't right click anywhere...
- Things seem sensitive, I find myself making errors which I can't always pinpoint that seem to relate to the touch doing things sporadically.
- The only gesture I can really use is two finger scrolling.
- The guide I was following fails on recompile telling me that it can't find GLX, I use my machine for 3D graphics and know this is working elsewhere.

I feel like touch support should be pretty good by now with the push in to mobile in 14.x. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: what do you mean "with really use" they don't work at all, or don't work the way you want them to?

Comment: I mean that every now and again I get a gesture, but I don't know where it came from (it's the application selector, but that's all). Other than that I just get two finger scrolling.

Comment: I've been digging for an answer on how to enable right click on touch-pad on my Macbook pro with Ubuntu 13.10 with no success. Then accidentally I tap on touch-pad with two fingers and guess what? That's the right click!